# Input variable is visible, but not accessable after Ajax , $each and Div clone process

Tags: javascript, jquery

I  was taken to the town square and stoned for my last posting about this for errors in my example code...haha. It due to stressing over this.  I had to delete it in the end.  Thanks for the rebuke guys it helps newbies like me learn.   Now I learnt from that and presented it all in a code run.

**My issue is**  The registration expire date is visible but when I click my test date input button it shows as empty.  I created a Code run/ Snippet that replicates the issue.

```
**Important.** 
Please remember to disable  the variable carDetailCloned.find('.mydate').val(person.registration); 
using // before enabling the test variables.
```

**card-container** is after the div/card had been cloned. I put the same mydate variable or one of the same variations of the same variable for testing below this.

```
$('.card-container').append(carDetailCloned);
```

**Results from variations below:**

```
 Data visible but Blank Alert so no difference.
//carDetailCloned.find('.mydate').val(person.registration);
```

```
Data visible,data found as it Alerts the visible data!, But the same date shows on all fields.
//$('.card').find('.mydate').val(person.registration);
```

**The end game**
I need to use that value in another script, but I can't select it.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){



 //simulates jason data result from Ajax
  var data = [
 
   {id:31,name:"Mike",surname:"Rynes",registration:1980},
   {id:32,name:"James",surname:"Bond",registration:2000},
   {id:33,name:"Helen",surname:"Wright",registration:1978},
  
  ];
  

     $.each(data, function( i, person ) {
    
    
      var carDetailCloned = $('.card').first().clone().show();
      
      carDetailCloned.find('.id').text(person.id);
      carDetailCloned.find('.name').text(person.name);
      carDetailCloned.find('.surname').text(person.surname);

      carDetailCloned.find('.mydate').val(person.registration);
      
      
      
      $('.card-container').append(carDetailCloned);
      
 //Remove Slashes below to test variations. One at a time please and make sure you disable the one above the card container first thanks.
      
       //carDetailCloned.find('.mydate').val(person.registration); 
       //$('.card').find('.mydate').val(person.registration);
       //$("#"+id).find('.mydate').val(person.registration);
    
  });
});








$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on('click', '.card .test-btn', function(event){
var mydate = $('.card').find('.mydate').val();
alert(mydate);

});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">




<div class="album py-1">
  <div class="container bg-light">
    <div class="row py-2">
      <div class="col-md-3 card-container" >
        <div class="card mb-3 shadow-sm"  style="display:none;">
          <div class="hover-container">
         </div>
          <div class="card-body CarDetail">
           <p class="card-text font-weight-bold">ID:
                 <span class="id"></span>
            </p>
            <p class="card-text font-weight-bold">Name:
                   <span class="name"></span>
            </p>
            <p class="card-text font-weight-bold">Surname:  
                <span class=" surname"></span>
            </p>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
              <p class="font-weight-bold ">Registration: 
                 <span class="font-weight-plain"></span>
                <span class="registration"></span> <span>Expires:
                
        <input  type="text" class="mydate" name="" value=""> </span> 
              </p>   
           
         
          </div>
            <p><button class="test-btn" >Test mydate input</button> </p>
           </div>
          </div>
        </div>   
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.closest()` to get closest card div where button is clicked then use `.find()` to find your input and show same.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 //simulates jason data result from Ajax
  var data = [

    {
      id: 31,
      name: "Mike",
      surname: "Rynes",
      registration: 1980
    },
    {
      id: 32,
      name: "James",
      surname: "Bond",
      registration: 2000
    },
    {
      id: 33,
      name: "Helen",
      surname: "Wright",
      registration: 1978
    },

  ];


  $.each(data, function(i, person) {


    var carDetailCloned = $('.card').first().clone().show();

    carDetailCloned.find('.id').text(person.id);
    carDetailCloned.find('.name').text(person.name);
    carDetailCloned.find('.surname').text(person.surname);
    carDetailCloned.find('.mydate').val(person.registration);
    $('.card-container').append(carDetailCloned);

  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.card .test-btn', function(event) {
  //use closest and find
    var mydate = $(this).closest('.card').find('.mydate').val();
    alert(mydate);

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">




<div class="album py-1">
  <div class="container bg-light">
    <div class="row py-2">
      <div class="col-md-3 card-container">
        <div class="card mb-3 shadow-sm" style="display:none;">
          <div class="hover-container">
          </div>
          <div class="card-body CarDetail">
            <p class="card-text font-weight-bold">ID:
              <span class="id"></span>
            </p>
            <p class="card-text font-weight-bold">Name:
              <span class="name"></span>
            </p>
            <p class="card-text font-weight-bold">Surname:
              <span class=" surname"></span>
            </p>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
              <p class="font-weight-bold ">Registration:
                <span class="font-weight-plain"></span>
                <span class="registration"></span> <span>Expires:
                
        <input  type="text" class="mydate" name="" value=""> </span>
              </p>


            </div>
            <p><button class="test-btn">Test mydate input</button> </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```